# Powershell - Calling select-string w/parameters from script args

Tags: powershell

I have a simple script to call select-string for a specific file extension.  I want to optionally provide other select-string params via script args.

my script findm.ps1

```
# simplified version to show error
select-string *.m -pattern $args[0] $args[1]
```

when I type `findm.ps1 someFileName -List`

I get the following error

```
Select-String : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '-List'.
```

typing the following form the cmd line works fine

```
select-string *.m -pattern "someFileName" -List
```

Thanks in advance

jra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The -List is being interpreted as a string (not an argument) by the parser, that needs to be associated with an argument.

Mike was close, but you need to reparse it as a powershell expression after you build your command string like this:

```
invoke-expression "select-string *.m -pattern $($args[0]) $($args[1])"
```

Comment: Thanx! Stuff like this makes it hard to like powershell.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
& "select-string *.m -pattern $($args[0]) $($args[1])"
```

Comment: no joy, I get the following err msg The term 'select-string *.m -pattern prodacal -List' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path
 was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

Comment: teach me to answer without trying the code.  invoke-expression (as zdan mentions) is the way to go.